# Can't move imported images

Tags: premiere

I'm using **Adobe Premiere CS3** and I can't determine how to move an imported image around. To move text I double-click on the text item on the items panel. I've tried hiding the text layer that keeps moving (the website URL that is displayed for the full length of the video) though a white box gets moved instead. Double-clicking on the image in the items panel doesn't do anything. This has nothing to do with animation or movement, I just need to change the image's position (it's dead-center by default).

How do I move an image to a different position in the *Timeline* panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had to move the image to "Video 5" (if there are four video layers) to be able to move the image around. Obnoxious though effective enough. If someone knows how to still move images around while avoiding having to add tons of video layers I'd appreciate it though.

Comment: You can do it in the effect controls panel by scrubbing the mouse on the position x and y values.

Comment: @stib "Scrubbing"?

Comment: Click and drag on the numbers to increase or decrease them. You can single click if you want to type the number. Clicking in the number field and using up and down arrows works too (use shift to increase x10)

Comment: @stib That is the video-in and video-out time in the *Project* panel, it was *nothing* to do with the layer `z-index` in the *Timeline* panel.

Comment: No, you can move any clip on any layer by changing its x and y position using the effect controls tab. Go to `Window>effect controls` to show it